# how to index xml documents in apache solr?

Tags: solr

I installed apache solr 4.5.1 in tomcat 7.0.47.

While installing I followed the procedure in the below link

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/install-apache-solr-tomcat/

Now, I want to know how to index the xml files into solr.

Can anyone explain the procedure step by step and provide example also?

Answer (score 1):

Step by step solr tutorial is provided in the official site itself. Please follow the steps in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_1/tutorial.html to get a basic understanding of solr

Comment: That is by using jetty server, but I deployed in tomcat. Here I don't have post.jar file.

Comment: You can post the documents using post.jar for any solr installation(tomcat/jetty). And post.jar is available as part of Solr itself.

Comment: Can you see the link I provided that i used while deploying the solr in tomcat server.